# Error when using Lemmatization and Tf- Idf calculation on Twitter data frame in Python

Tags: python, tf-idf, lemmatization

I have a data frame of tweets and I'm trying to calculate Tf-Idf on the lemmatized 'tweet' column. I have a problem with the results of the lemmatization and I'm getting an error when trying to calculate the Tf-Idf.

Below is my code:

```
w_tokenizer = nltk.tokenize.WhitespaceTokenizer()
lemmatizer=WordNetLemmatizer()

def lemmatize_text(tweet):
    return [lemmatizer.lemmatize(w) for w in w_tokenizer.tokenize(tweet)]

df['tweet_lemmatized'] = df['tweet'].apply(lemmatize_text)
```

This is an example of the data frame with the new column 'tweet_lemmatized':

```
  target       tweet_lemmatized
    0        [believe, department, year, released, hoping]
    1        [huge, expected, tomorrow, night, beginning]
```

It didn't work well because there are words like 'hoping', 'beginning' in the column.

My first question- How can I improve the lemmatization?

Now I want to calculate the Tf- Idf for this column and produce new columns in my data frame with the top words.

This is my code for the Tf-Idf:
I want to add the top words to my original data frame 'df'.

```
from sklearn.feature_extraction.text import TfidfVectorizer, ENGLISH_STOP_WORDS

tfidf= TfidfVectorizer(ngram_range=(1,2), max_features=100,  
       stop_words=ENGLISH_STOP_WORDS).fit(df.tweet_lemmatized)

tfidf_tweet = tfidf.transform(df.tweet_lemmatized)

result=pd.DataFrame(tfidf_tweet.toarray(), columns=tfidf.get_feature_names())
```

This is the error I got:

```
AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'lower'
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`TfidfVectorizer.fit` takes string input not list(your `df.tweet_lemmatized` data should contain strings not lists).
For the better lemmatization, you can use `nltk.pos_tag` to get parts of speech and then lemmatize words based on their tag, for example:

```
lemmatizer.lemmatize(word, 'v')
```

This way it will lemmatize `word` considering it is a verb.

Comment: Thanks! Your suggestion regarding the lemmatization worked. What should I do with the  df.tweet_lemmatized column? Can you explain more?

Comment: The `TfidfVectorizer.fit` itself extracts words from a text(string), so you need to pass string to it; You can use `df.tweet_lemmatized = df.tweet_lemmatized.str.join(' ') `. @Lili

Comment: O.k. Now it works. I'm trying to add the columns with the tf-idf calculation (The columns that don't contain only zeros) to my original data frame 'df'. How can I do that?

Comment: You can make a dataframe from the bag of words you got from the `transform`'s output and then concatenate it with your dataframe (don't forget to use `list(bagOfWords.toarray())` for the `pd.DataFrame`'s input). You can also only take the top words from the `transform` by setting `max_features` for the `TfidfVectorizer`'s constructor. @Lili

Comment: The concatenate doesn't perform well. It added Null to the df. Here is what I did: 
  Tfidf_tweet = Tfidf.transform(df.tweet_lemmatized); result=pd.DataFrame(Tfidf_tweet.toarray(), columns=Tfidf.get_feature_names())
    ; df_concat = pd.concat([df, result], axis=1)  Do you know why?

Comment: Set the index in `pd.DataFrame` to your original dataframe's index. @Lili

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/218667/discussion-between-lili-and-mobina).

Answer (score 0):

Either you can use `PorterStemmer()` or make modifications to `WordNetLemmatizer()`.

```
stemmer = nltk.PorterStemmer()
stemmer.step('hoping')
```

OR:

```
lemmatizer = WordNetLemmatizer()
lemmatizer.lemmatize("running", 'v')
```